# images are displaying in simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to load images from url and those images are displaying perfectly in simulator but not on the iphone. Any ideas on what could be the problem?
here is code

```
uiImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, iImageViewStart, 200, iImageHeight-50)];

uiImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
        if (succeeded) {
            uiImageView.image = image;
        }
    }];
[scroll addSubview:uiImageView];
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
`UIImageView *iconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, 40, 40)];`
    [self downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
        if (succeeded) {
            iconImage.image = image;
            tmpImage = image;
        }
    }];
//iconImage.image =tmpImage;
iconImage.layer.cornerRadius=20;
iconImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
iconImage.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];`
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
    FinalProdDisplay *FinalProdDisplayView = [ [FinalProdDisplay alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalProdDisplay" bundle:nil];
Product *product = [ [Product alloc] init];
product= [arrayProducts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
FinalProdDisplayView.strUrl=product.strProductImageUrl;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What you have tried? Can you post Some Code??

Comment: sorry my crystal ball got broken yesterday.... seriously... you need to provide some code nobody will help you only with this information

Comment: The simulator accepts a wider range of image formats. Sometimes you had a specific file type that the device cannot display. Double check files format.

Comment: Since we have to guess with the given limited info, are you sure your device is connected to the internet?

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota What image format does the simulator support, that the device doesn't? I use a pretty diverse range of image types (color spaces, bpc, alpha settings, etc.) and have never seen an image that the simulator could show, but the device couldn't (except for non-image related reasons such as capitalization, size, connectivity, etc.).

Comment: Also, is the URL accessible on the device? E.g. if you're using `localhost` in your URL, that might work on the simulator, but not the device.

Comment: above i was posted code please any one help me

Comment: hello @SibaPrasadHota iam not using 'localhost' in my URL. I have ip address

Comment: with the same code above i posted images are displaying as tableview icon image but not displaying when i goto DetailViewController by calling didSelectRowAtIndexpath delegate method.

Comment: From your code, i can see you are adding the image to scroll view. can you post the code for your Tableview `CellforRowAtIndexPath` and `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath` ? Then we can solve the issue.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota i was posted code what you required please give a suggestion

Comment: @Siva show your .h file.. I would like to see how you declared the image

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota just normal declaration as UIImageView *uiImageView;

Comment: You are using **url** in `CellforRow` and **product.strProductImageUrl**  in `DidSelectRow`  can you put NSLOG and Check whether Both the URL same or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your image names.
iOS Simulator is **case insensitive**,while device is **case -sensitive**.
So, double check image filenames.

Comment: Images are coming from URL so i dont think that will be the case.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota If file URL, I think this issue would still apply. If it's a URL referencing a server, then you're quite right, that the capitalization of the wouldn't change behavior between device and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I checked server URL which was starting with http:// ....

I replaced http with https and my images in iOS app started showing up.